# get word from string but not in html tags using python regex

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-3.x

i want to search a word from a paragraph, paragraph has html text also.
but i want word only in simple text which are not in html tags.

for eg.

```
post_content = """I have a question about xyz.
                I have a question about xyz .
                I have a question about xyz?
                I have a question about <a href="hello">xyz</a>.
                I have a question about <a href="hello">abc xyz</a>
                 xyz
                *xyz"""
```

i don't want xyz from `<a></a>`.

please give me a regex for that,
i have tried `[^<.+?>]xyz`

see demo : [DEMO](https://pythex.org/?regex=%5B%5E%3C.%2B%3F%3E%5Dxyz&test_string=I%20have%20a%20question%20about%20xyz.%0AI%20have%20a%20question%20about%20xyz%20.%0AI%20have%20a%20question%20about%20xyz%3F%0AI%20have%20a%20question%20about%20%3Ca%20href%3D%22hello%22%3Exyz%3C%2Fa%3E.%0AI%20have%20a%20question%20about%20%3Ca%20href%3D%22hello%22%3Eabc%20xyz%3C%2Fa%3E%0A%20xyz%0A*xyz&ignorecase=0&multiline=1&dotall=0&verbose=0)

### updated code

```
post_content = <above string>
keyword = "xyz"
pattern = r"(?!((?!<).)*<\/)%s" % keyword
replace = "<a href='#'>xyz</a>" 
post_content = re.sub(pattern, replace, post_content)
print "post_content", post_content
```

Comment: check now.this code is working for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Pattern

```
(?!((?!<).)*<\/)xyz
```

**View live <kbd>[REGEXP](http://regex101.com/r/nG1gU7/6#python)</kbd>**

[image]

It uses negative lookahahead and says that the match should be between `<` and `</`.

Comment: there is one problem i update this expression to my python code it not work.please see my updated question.

Comment: @i'mPosSible dont use match.use search instead.

Comment: @i'mPosSible your post_content syntaxt is wrong.it should be """<ur lines> """

Comment: yea, but there is not static string i get this this from html FORM and its type is unicode.

Comment: @i'mPosSible for mulitline strings that is the format.you have to enclose it between `"""` and `"""`

Answer (score 2):

Just use a negative lookahead to match all `xyz` strings which are not present within the tags.

```
xyz(?![^<>]*<\/)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/nG1gU7/7)

```
>>> import re
>>> s = """I have a question about xyz.
... I have a question about xyz .
... I have a question about xyz?
... I have a question about <a href="hello">xyz</a>.
... I have a question about <a href="hello">abc xyz</a>
...  xyz
... *xyz"""
>>> m = re.findall(r'xyz(?![^<>]*<\/)', s)
>>> for i in m:
...     print i
... 
xyz
xyz
xyz
xyz
xyz
```